# If select found more than one rows make it choose last row

Tags: mysql

I have create a view to select something from table. If I didn't put the `group by column_name` at last it view show more than one rows per `id`.

For example:

```
|parent_id|id|category|
|01       |01|4wheel  |
|02       |02|2wheel  |
|03       |03|drive   |
|04       |04|ride    |
|05       |01|car     |
|06       |02|bike    |
|07       |03|van     |
|08       |04|bicycle |
```

how can I get only last category that found on select table before group by id like

```
|id|category|
|01|car     |
|02|bike    |
|03|van     |
|04|bicycle |
```

Comment: Why you are not trying `SELECT MAX(id)` ?

Comment: @erman999 it's a table that create from many to many relationship so the id can be duplicate. so, Max(id) can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the table name is `TEST`. Following self explanatory query you can use in order to obtained the desired result.

```
SELECT id, category
FROM TEST
WHERE parent_id IN (
    SELECT MAX(parent_id)
    FROM TEST
    GROUP BY id
);
```

Let's go dry-run

```
-- create
CREATE TABLE TEST (
  parent_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  category varchar(20) NOT NULL
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1, 1, '4wheel');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2, 2, '2wheel');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (3, 3, 'drive');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (4, 4, 'ride');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (5, 1, 'car');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (6, 2, 'bike');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (7, 3, 'van');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (8, 4, 'bicycle');


-- fetch 
SELECT id, category
FROM TEST
WHERE parent_id IN (
    SELECT MAX(parent_id)
    FROM TEST
    GROUP BY id
);


Output:

1|car
2|bike
3|van
4|bicycle
```

Comment: on the working view I have join like 4 table and when I try your solution it make my db freeze. so, I can see the result

Comment: Oh dear, you haven't added the full details. The given answer is as per the question asked. As far as query time execution is concerned for your original problem, you must check the design in the first place and also try to utilize the indexes.

Comment: I have solved it by manual change category now